# Does any of Cloudera Hadoop distribution supports Apache Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Apache Spark. I heard that none of the versions of CDH are supposrting Apache Spark SQL as of now, same case with hortonworks distribution as well. Is that true..?

And another one is I have CDH 5.0.0 installed in my PC, which version of Apache Spark my CDH supports..?

Also could someone please provide me the steps to execute my Spark program in my CDH distribution. I have written some basic programs using Apache Spark 1.2 version and I am not able to run those programs in CDH environment, i am facing very basic problem when I am running Spark program using spark-submit command

> spark-submit: Command not found

Do i need to configure anything prior to run my Spark program..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the distributions of CDH include the whole Spark distribution, including Spark SQL.

EDIT: It is supported as of CDH 5.5.x.

CDH 5.0.x includes Spark 0.9.x. CDH 5.3.x includes Spark 1.2.x and 5.4.x should ship 1.3.x since it is about to be released upstream.

`spark-submit` is already part of your path if you are using CDH. If you're running from somewhere else, you have to put this file on your path or give the full path to it. This is the same as any program. So, this is something wrong with what you set up.